# Разработка ежедневника с повторяющимися событиями

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Доброе время суток!

Раньше пользовался прекрасной софтинкой, но она более не поддерживается (с 2006 года). Она занималась тем, что выводила определенные события на волпапер в виде календаря.

Решил попробовать написать аналог, и собственно завис, как лучше рассчитывать повторяющиеся даты (например ежегодные, еженедельные, ежемесячные, каждый вторник четной недели и т.п.)... Гуглил, но примеры все уходят в outlook, sharepoint, google calendar...

Есть ли какая-то готовая реализация по построению таких событий? Просто дело не из простых, и писать свое - это большой труд...

PS: Хранилище или компонент должен быть бесплатным и желательно opensource.

Спасибо, если натолкнете на мысль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в своё время писал такое сам вручную. Пересчитывал всё в дни, учитывал високосные года и всё такое.

Может быть, вам поможет [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/)?

Comment: @VladD, Ну вот я себя морально готовлю к написанию своего, потому как ничего готового не могу найти. Склоняюсь к тому, чтобы каждое событие знало, должно ли оно еще выполниться, и дату следующего выполнения. Если дата выполнения меньше текущей, попробовать пересчитать все. 

Если с разовыми, ежегодными и ежедневными все понятно, то вот с еженедельными, как-то я в небольшой панике, особенно с учитыванием каждой вторую неделю, каждую 3-ю... Еженедельно во вторник и четверг... В общем пока нормально в голове алгоритм не сложился.

Может есть где почитать про логику таких приложений?

Answer (score 0):

Ежедневный, ежегодный и т.п. — это все промежутки времени. Их можно представить в виде секунд и добавлять к конкретной дате преобразовав ее в timestamp.

Вариант реализации можно [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/204628/#comment_7055310) посмотреть.